# javascript get json inner value

Tags: javascript, json

Let's I have next object

```
   var o = { "foo" : {"bar" : "omg"} };
```

I can get value of key `foo` using

```
o["foo"] // return {"bar" : "omg"}
```

and I can get value of key `bar` inside `foo` using

```
o["foo"]["bar"]  // return "omg"
```

Can I get value of key `bar` inside `foo` using brackets `[]` single time.
Somethong like

```
o["foo.bar"] // not working(
```

or

```
o["foo/bar"] // not working(
```

Comment: whats wrong with `o['foo']['bar']` or `o.foo.bar`?

Comment: No you can't do that , but you could do `o.foo.bar´

Comment: Obviously you wouldn't ask it if you just need to get 'omg' yet another way, right? Do you need to find the name of the o.foo property (which would be `bar`), right?

Comment: I have path to inner element like string 'foo.bar', and I want get inner element by string

Comment: I have object `o` and string `'foo.bar'`, and i want get `"omg"`. So I can't use `o.foo.bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly common to create a getter function to do something like this. From the comment:

> I have object o and string 'foo.bar', and i want get "omg".

```
var getProp = function (theObject, propString) {
    var current = theObject;
    var split = propString.split('.');

    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (current.hasOwnProperty(split[i])) {
            current = current[split[i]];
        }
    }

    return current;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MXu2M/

Note: this is a thrown together example, you'd want to bullet proof and buff it up before dropping it on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can only use `o["foo"]["bar"]` or `o.foo.bar`

Answer (score 0):

No, you must use `o["foo"]["bar"]` because it's an object inside another object. If you want to access it with "foo.bar", it means you must create the first object like this:

```
var o = {"foo.bar": "omg"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`o["foo.bar"]` or `o["foo/bar"]` are not valid for your example. You could use this notation that is cleaner:

```
var bar = o.foo.bar // bar will contain 'omg'
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a way, but I'm not sure this is what you asked for:

```
eval("o.foo.bar");
```

it is dangerous though, and doesn't use `[]` , but if what you want is to use a string for  accessing any object it works